# BusterJs test in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, buster.js

I've the follwoing test. For some reason the `@$e` I've set in the before function is undefined in the test:

```
assert = buster.assert
buster.testCase 'BaseChart',

  before: ->
    @el = sinon.spy()
    @$el = [@el]
    console.log(@$el) 
    ##[LOG] [function spy() {}]

  'updates when the model changed': ->
    console.log(@$el)
    ##[LOG] undefined
```

Comment: What is `@` inside `before` and `'updates when the model changed'`?

Comment: It seems to be the buster test case.

Comment: Yo @AndreasKöberle can you mark the answer on this

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess but change:

`before: ->` to `before: =>`

And see if that helps.